# Left join even if no pivot

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `settings` table that holds all possible settings and the default value for each.
I also have a `setting_user` table that holds user settings. This is a pivot table between the User and the Setting.
If a row exists in `setting_user` for UserA, then it overrides the default value of the setting.
If no row exists in `setting_user` for UserA, then the value of the setting is the default value.

Here is my migration:

```
        Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('key');
            //$table->json('default_value')->nullable();
            $table->text('default_value')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('setting_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->uuid('user_id')->index();
            $table->uuid('setting_id')->index();
            $table->text('setting_value')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I want to return a Collection of ALL the rows in the `settings` table for UserA, with a join on the `setting_user`.

In other words, if there are 50 rows in the `settings` table, I want to return 50 items, no matter if UserA has a match/pivot entry for each in `setting_user`.

Use case is the following: Users can have custom settings (value of the custom setting is held in `setting_user` in column `setting_value`). If they never set a custom setting, pivot row does not exist, so we consider the setting value as the `default_value` column in `settings` table.

I started with something like this, in `\App\User`:

```
$defaultAndUserSettings = \App\Setting::query()
    ->join('setting_user', 'settings.id', '=', 'setting_user.setting_id', 'left outer')
    ->where('setting_user.user_id', $this->id)
    //-> plus also all other Setting rows where the user has no pivot for
    ->get();
```

but I could not find a way to make it work. The above will only return Settings where a pivots exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are applying `->where('setting_user.user_id', $this->id)` to Setting query.

It means database will ignore those settings that `setting_user.user_id` IS NULL.

So if you want to keep the settings which without `setting_user`. You need to put the condition in join closure:

```php
$defaultAndUserSettings = \App\Setting::query()
    ->leftJoin('setting_user', function($join) {
          $join->on('settings.id', '=', 'setting_user.setting_id', 'left outer')
               ->where('setting_user.user_id', $this->id); // Apply where condition here.      
      })
```